# Filter 2 coordinate index in xarray dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I am trying to filter large dataset in xarray for exact `latitude`, `longitude` values from following dataset:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 23, level: 6, longitude: 21, time: 178486)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 ... 2019-11-26T21:00:00
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 46.5 46.25 46.0 45.75 ... 41.5 41.25 41.0
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 18.0 18.25 18.5 18.75 ... 22.5 22.75 23.0
  * level      (level) int32 750 800 850 900 950 1000
Data variables:
    cbh        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    clwc       (time, level, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    t          (time, level, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    vetar      (time, level, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    sp         (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2019-05-11 06:14:51 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.10.0: /opt/ecmw...
```

I am trying to do it with where statement, but it seems like I need to compare arrays in order to do this.
 With `DS1.where(DS1.longitude==22.0 and DS1.latitude==43.5,drop=True)` I get famous error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I can perform this filtering in two steps, first with

```
ds22=DS1.where(DS1.longitude==22.0,drop=True)
```

and then with

```
ds22435=ds22.where(ds22.latitude==43.5,drop=True)
```

But is there any way of doing this in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`Dataset.sel`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.sel.html) (see also examples [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data)).  I think something like the following would suit your needs:

```py
result = DS1.sel(latitude=43.5, longitude=22.0)
```